How to use lightning-file-upload component on a not yet created record?
I have a community page where I have a order form and where I want the user to be able to upload files. But it seems like the record that the file will be "linked" too neeeds to be created before you can upload a file. But I HAVE to HAVE this upload component when the order is placed. Are there any workarounds?
I have heard about the upload files salesforce api, but I have never used apis before.

Children can't exist before their parents. This is true in both biology and relational databases. As a workaround to this problem, upload the file using the user's Id instead, which will store the file in the user's personal files folder. Once the order is created, you can then attach it to the order using some kind of automation, such as an After Insert Record-Triggered Flow. It's not possible to attach the file to the order any earlier than this.
